# iOS Build disappear on itunes

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

i'm trying to upload my app build on itunes. after successfully uploading the build the build appears in Activity in processing stage. After 5 mins when i refresh the page my build disappear.

This is happening for almost 1 week. I have searched for its solution and tried many of them but nothing is working. How can i submit my built?

When upload the build through xcode it show me like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3OJg.jpg)

When it verify my account detail with certiicate and provisioning profile its shows nothing in that
[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QttIo.jpg)

I have tried all the possible solution and checked my `info.plist` file but nothing works, how can i submit my built?

Comment: Have you tested this build in real device?

Comment: @ihtasham Afzal: Check your mailbox associated with this apple developer account, As apple may have sent you error description. Your application may have some errors to approve on apple store.

Comment: I had faced this kind of issues. It was happed when permission was not asked from user like camera access, photo library access, etc. i.e. missing key in info.plist file

Comment: Yup, i have tested on real device it is working fine on device.
I have also check my info plist file thatis also fine everything is provided. But still  i'm facing this. @MahendraGP

Comment: Did you contact Apple support ? that's your best shot IMHO and usually they answer within a day or 2 max.

Answer (score 0):

If you are opening camera or gallery from your application then you need to add Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description (in case you are opening gallery) and Privacy - Camera Usage Description (in case you are opening camera) into your info.plist file.

This kind of issues happened when those are missing from your info.plist file.

Hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: I have write already all these things in my application that you mentioned in the comment but i am still facing this problem

Comment: This usually happens when permissions are missing from info.plist file. Are you using location or any other feature and didn't add the privacy description in the info.plist file? Please check once.